# Root system G_2

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to find the TikZ code of the root system of the lie algebra of type `$G_2$`.

[image: wanted]

(Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Root_system_G2.svg)

I would be extremely thankful if anyone could provide me with a code or a reference.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach\ang in {60,120,...,360}{
     \draw[->,blue!80!black,thick] (0,0) -- (\ang:2cm);
    }
    \foreach\ang in {30,90,...,330}{
     \draw[->,blue!80!black,thick] (0,0) -- (\ang:3cm);
    }
    \draw[magenta,->](1,0) arc(0:150:1cm)node[pos=0.1,right,scale=0.5]{$5\pi/6$};
    \node[anchor=south west,scale=0.6] at (2,0) {$\alpha$};
    \node[anchor=north,scale=0.6] at (1,3) {$G_{2}$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user11112 You are welcome.

Comment: I think this no comment stuff is getting a little hostile. I chose this one to comment since it was a relatively positive encounter.

Comment: From your point of view yes maybe it doesn't give you a right to be overreaching either now does it? If you think I'm being hostile then I don't have anything to add. If it is the attempt or effort etc. then don't answer it if you really care about it. Why do you bother at all ?

Comment: @HarishKumar All I'm saying is that if you bothered to write an answer then putting no comments on top of it looks like passive aggression. That's all.

Answer (score 6):

Another `tikz` solution with different focus and with a few comments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}% arrow tip library
\usetikzlibrary{bending}% better arrow head for bended lines

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    % arrow heads for all lines (with narrower arrow head width)
    -{Straight Barb[bend,
       width=\the\dimexpr10\pgflinewidth\relax,
       length=\the\dimexpr12\pgflinewidth\relax]},
  ]
    % straight arrows
    \foreach \i in {0, 1, ..., 5} {
      \draw[thick, blue] (0, 0) -- (\i*60:2);
      \draw[thick, blue] (0, 0) -- (30 + \i*60:3.5);
    }
    % arc arrow
    \draw[thin, red] (1.5, 0) arc[radius=1.5, start angle=0, end angle=5*30];
    % annotations
    \node[right] at (2, 0) {$\alpha$};
    \node[above left, inner sep=.2em] at (5*30:3.5) {$\beta$};
    \node[right] at (15:1.5) {$5\pi/6$};
    \node at (1.5, 3) {$G_2$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Didn't you actually forget to use the `bend` key?

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido,pstricks}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-2.85,-3)(2.6,3)
\SpecialCoor
  \multido{\iA = 0+60, \iB = 30+60}{6}{%
   {\psset{arrows = ->, linewidth = 1.5\pslinewidth, linecolor = blue}
    \rput{\iA}(0,0){\psline(0,0)(2,0)}
    \rput{\iB}(0,0){\psline(0,0)(3,0)}}}
  \psarc[linecolor = red]{->}{1.5}{0}{150}
  \rput(3;60){$G_{2}$}
 {\small
  \rput(2;15){$5\pi/6$}
  \rput(2.2;0){$\alpha$}
  \rput(3.2;150){$\beta$}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

With LuaLaTeX and MetaPost.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}

u = 1.75cm; path Gradius[];

beginfig(1)
  drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 1.25bp withcolor .5blue);
  for i = 0 upto 11:
    angl := 30i;
    Gradius[i] = origin -- if odd i: 3u*dir angl else: 2u*dir angl fi; 
    drawarrow Gradius[i];
  endfor
  drawoptions();
  label.rt(btex $\alpha$ etex, point 1 of Gradius[0]);
  label.lft(btex $\beta$ etex, point 1 of Gradius[5]);
  drawarrow halfcircle scaled (2u) cutafter Gradius[5] withcolor .5red;
  label.rt(btex $5\pi/6$ etex, u*dir 15);
  label.bot(btex $G_2$ etex, (1.25u, 3u)); 
endfig

\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try the [rank-2-roots](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.7478.1535731234.5100.ctan-ann@ctan.org) package, now on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rank-2-roots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{rootSystem}{G}
\roots
\end{rootSystem}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It follows the style of Fulton and Harris, but using polygons rather than vectors to make the roots easier for your eye ball to organize. It also handles Weyl chambers and parabolic subgroups. It only works for simple rank 2 root systems so far.